# ros install on debian sid

Tags: ros, installation, rosdep, ros-fuerte, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed fuerte catkin on my amd64/sid.
`rosdep check ros_comm` ran OK.
But `rosdep install turtlesim` returned

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
> to system dependencies:
> turtlesim: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [debian]

Thus I updated my file `rosdep.yaml` by adding these lines:

> qt4-qmake:
> debian: qt4-qmake

I updated the file `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` by adding this line:

> yaml file:///home/fabien/robot/ros/ros/rosdep.yaml debian

But `rosdep update` ends with this error:

> ERROR: invalid sources list file:
> line:
> yaml file:///home/fabien/robot/ros/ros/rosdep.yaml debian
> url must be a fully-specified URL with scheme, hostname, and path: file:///home/fabien/robot/ros/ros/rosdep.yaml

Any hints

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40543/ros-install-on-debian-sid/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2012-08-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2012-08-11**:
@joq: Ok. I will give a try to commit my changes. As I'm not yet familiar with git, I hope I will not mess things up :-)

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2012-08-11**:
I encountered this problem while I tested the update from my git repository: `ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/theedge123/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/debian.yaml]: mapping values are not allowed here in "<string>", line 6, column 19:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best solution is to [contribute the missing rules](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html).

That way, the problem you discovered will be fixed for other Debian users.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem as you have. In my case, I've gotten it to work with the same sentence without "debian" at the end.

That is to say: yaml file:///home/fabien/robot/ros/ros/rosdep.yaml

Obviously with my package path.

I hope it helps you

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) with karma: 375 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1